# Number of naturals which cannot be expressed in the form $xa+yb=1$ for coprime $a,b$

Tags: number-theory

I was playing around with a few numbers.I noticed the following:

Given two coprime naturals $a$ and $b$,we can express a lot of integers in the form $xa+yb=d$ for $x,y\ge0$ and $x$ and $y$ are integers.

However, there are some others which I could not express in the form I just described.For example, if $a=7$ and $b=5$, I could not express 1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,13,16,18 and 23 as above.There might be more of them.That brought to my mind a question.

Given two coprime positive integers $(a,b),a>1,b>1$,is the number of natural numbers which cannot be expressed in the form above finite? Can we exactly calculate how many of them exist?.

Comment: Every $d\ge(a-1)(b-1)$ can be so expressed; exactly half of the non-negative integers less than $(a-1)(b-1)$ can be so expressed.

Comment: @xavierm02: $a$ and $b$ are required to be relatively prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Frobenius coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), also sometimes called the postage-stamp problem (though that name also refers to another problem) or, more recently, the McNugget problem. [Sylvester proved](http://www.archive.org/stream/mathematicalque05unkngoog#page/n150/mode/2up) that every $d\ge(a-1)(b-1)$ can be so represented and that exactly half of the non-negative integers less than $(a-1)(b-1)$ have such representations. [This web page](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) gives a proof of the theorem.

Comment: Looking at the $a=7$, $b=5$ example, you'll see that $d$ can be expressed if and only if $23-d$ can't. This is where the "exactly half" in Brian's answer comes from.