# Prove by induction that every integer n, n>=0 can be represented by 5a+7b for a, b in Z

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I feel that I could solve this question normally, especially given the closely-related question on this site, but I'm having trouble approaching it by induction.

I assume that 5a + 7b = n is true, then I try to show that it holds true for n+1. I'm assuming that I can't use the same a and b for the second equality, so I wrote it as 5a₂ +7b₂ = n+1.

From here, I substituted 5a + 7b for n, simplified and got to 5(a₂ - a) + 7(b₂ - b) = 1. I'm not sure if that's right or where to go from here

Comment: **Hint:**  Try to find a multiple of $5$ and a multiple of $7$ that differ by $1$.

Comment: Other people already answered, but I just want to point out that induction relies on proving the fact for the base case first, so you should start with proving that you can find $a$ and $b$ such that $5a+7b=0$!

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not sure if your comment is serious or not, but, since we need to prove the equality for $n\geq 0$, we actually need to consider the case $5a + 7b =0$. The exclamation mark was just that, not a factorial :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that every integer can be written in the form $5a + 7b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295788/show-that-every-integer-can-be-written-in-the-form-5a-7b-for-a-b-in-mathb). One answer uses induction, too.

Comment: @CarlosSantiToledo Yes, you are right. I was distracted by $0!$

Comment: A better question would have been to show that every integer $n\ge 24$ can be represented as $n=5a+7b$ for some *nonnegative* integers $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this:

$$3 \cdot 5 - 2 \cdot 7 = 1$$

Hence, for every $n$:

$$ (3n) \cdot 5 + (-2n) \cdot 7 = n$$

Or is this too simple? :-)

If it must be done, using induction, you can do this:

Start with:

$$5a + 7b = n$$
and
$$3 \cdot 5 + (-2) \cdot 7 = 1$$

Hence:

$$ (a + 3) \cdot 5 + (b - 2) \cdot 7 = n + 1$$